# Problem linking .so and .lib on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having trouble linking some files to my project. It's an android studio project and I want to link one external file: "Emv_lib.so" (I know that are some questions on how to link .so files, but those are about internal .so files, this is an external one.)

Beside this file, I have an emv_lib.lib and emvIIapi.h (the header file that actually contains the functions that i need to call). I cannot get this to work. I tried with CMakeList, putting the emvIIapi.h file in there, but it comes with the error: "Execution failed for task ':app:configureCMakeDebug'.
C/C++"

I follow some suggestion, to create in src/main the folder jniLibs and put your .so files in there, but it didn't work.

From my undestanding, I have to compile, somehow, either the .so files or the .lib file.

I'm new to android studio, so don't go hard on me. Thank you for your time!